# Spark, applying filters on DataFrame(or RDD) multiple times without redundant evaluations

Tags: scala, apache-spark, lazy-evaluation

I have a Spark DataFrame that needs heavy evaluations for the chaining of the parent RDDs.

```
val df: DataFrame[(String, Any)] = someMethodCalculatingDF()
val out1 = df.filter(_._1 == "Key1").map(_._2).collect()
val out2 = df.filter(_._1 == "Key2").map(_._2)
```

`out1` is a very small data ( one or two Rows in each partition)  and collected for further use. 
`out2` is a Dataframe and will be used to generate another RDD that will be materialized later. 
So, `df` will be evaluated twice, which is heavy.

`Caching` could be a solution, but in my application, it wont be, because the data could be really really BIG. The memory would be overflowed.

Is there any genius :) who could suggest another way bypassing the redundant evaluations?

Comment: Could you do the filter before `someMethodCalculatingDF`? You would still run the method twice but the amount of data would be different (a lot less when computing `out1`).

Comment: no.. unfortunately.. T^T

Answer (score 2):

It's actually a scenario which occurs in our cluster on a daily basis. From our experience this methodology work for us the best.

When we need to use same calculated dataframe twice(on different branches) we do as follows:

1. Calculation phase is heavy and resulted in a rather small dataframe -> cache it.
2. Calculation phase is light resulted in a big dataframe -> let it calculate twice.
3. Calculation is heavy resulted in a big data frame -> write it to disk(HDFS or S3) split the job on splitting point to two different batch processing job. In this you don't repeat the heavy calculation and you don't shred your cache(which will either way probably use the disk).
4. Calculation phase is light resulting in a small Dataframe. Your life is good and you can go home :).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with dataset API so will write a solution using RDD api.

```
val rdd: RDD[(String, Int)] = ???

//First way
val both: Map[String, Iterable[Int]] = rdd.filter(e => e._1 == "Key1" || e._1 == "Key2")
  .groupByKey().collectAsMap()

//Second way
val smallCached = rdd.filter(e => e._1 == "Key1" || e._1 == "Key2").cache()
val out1 = smallCached.filter(_._1 == "Key1").map(_._2).collect()
val out2 = smallCached.filter(_._1 == "Key2").map(_._2).collect()
```